# Connecting to the local postgres database from the Docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

My task was to write a script that received information from a remote computer and recorded the received information on a locally located Postgres DataBase. Tests were successful. The data came, the database was updated.

The next step was to place this script in the docker container. Dockerfile and Docker-Compose.yml are attached below. I add environment with working programs to the container through Volume. The docker container runs on the local machine where the postgres data base is located. When I run the image, I control the workflow of the program and watch the data being received from the remote computer, but writing messages to the postgres data base at the address - `postgres + psycopg2: // postgres: hi123 @ localhost: 5432 /` Back does not occur.

How can I solve the problem of connecting the docker container to a locally located database?

```
=---------Dockerfile---------=
FROM python:latest
WORKDIR /backend
COPY requirements.txt /backend/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
=----------------------------=

=-----Docker-compose.yml-----=
    version: '3'

    services:
      back:
        image: git_rep_2_back:latest
        environment:
          - PYTHONPATH=/backend/
        volumes:
          - "./Platform:/backend"
        command: bash -c "cd server && python launcher.py"
=-----------------------------=

=-------configfile_for_connection_to_database-------=

postgres+psycopg2://postgres:hi123@localhost:5432/Back

=---------------------------------------------------=
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: i'm using docker compose for running container. And i need to configure docker-compose.yml for right connection with postgres. May be u know how can i configure it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to connect to "localhost" from within the container. In colloquial terms, "localhost" refers to "this computer" or "the computer I am working on". All requests to localhost will be redirected back to any processes listening on the localhost interface. Inside a container, the `localhost` interface is different from that of `localhost` outside the container. In this case, you should consider making your database either listen on `0.0.0.0` or your machine's IP address. Then, from within the container, you can connect to your database using your machine's IP address.

Hope this helps!